# Passing the Div id to another vue component in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I created a simple real-time chat application using vue js in laravel. 
I am having a problem with the automatic scroll of the div when there is a new data. 
What I want is the div to automatically scroll down to the bottom of the div when there is a new data.

Here is my code so far.

Chat.vue file

```
<template>
  <div class="panel-block">
    <div class="chat" v-if="chats.length != 0" style="height: 400px;" id="myDiv">
      <div v-for="chat in chats" style="overflow: auto;" >
        <div class="chat-right" v-if="chat.user_id == userid">
          {{ chat.chat }}
        </div>
        <div class="chat-left" v-else>

          {{ chat.chat}}
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div v-else class="no-message">
      <br><br><br><br><br>
      There are no messages
    </div>
    <chat-composer v-bind:userid="userid" v-bind:chats="chats" v-bind:adminid="adminid"></chat-composer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['chats','userid','adminid'],   
  }
</script>
```

ChatComposer.vue file

```
<template>

  <div class="panel-block field">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" v-on:keyup.enter="sendChat" v-model="chat">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" v-on:click="sendChat">Send Chat</button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
export default{
  props: ['chats','userid','adminid'],
  data() {
    return{
      chat: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {

    sendChat: function(e) {
      if(this.chat != ''){
        var data = {
          chat: this.chat,
          admin_id: this.adminid,
          user_id: this.userid
        }

        this.chat = ''; 

        axios.post('/chat/sendChat', data).then((response) => { 
          this.chats.push(data)
        })

        this.scrollToEnd();

      }
    },
    scrollToEnd: function() {       
      var container = this.$el.querySelector("#myDiv");
      container.scrollTop = container.scrollHeight;
    }

  }
}   

</script>
```

I am passing a div id from the Chat.vue file to the ChatComposer.vue file.

As you can see in the `ChatComposer.vue` file there is a function called `scrollToEnd` where in it gets the height of the div id from `Chat.vue` file.

When the `sendchat` function is triggered i called the `scrollToEnd` function.

I guess hes not getting the value from the div id because I am getting an error - Cannot read property `'scrollHeight'` of null.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: user props method to pass value

Answer (score 0):

the scope of `this.$el.querySelector` will be limited to only ChatComposer.vue hence child component can not able to access  div of parent component `#myDiv` .

You can trigger event as below in ChatComposer

```
this.$emit('scroll');
```

In parent component write ScollToEnd method and use $ref to assign new height

```
<chat-composer v-bind:userid="userid" v-bind:chats="chats" v-bind:adminid="adminid" @scroll="ScollToEnd"></chat-composer>
```

..

Comment: Yeah this is a good use case for events. I'd create a dedicated event bus. Either that or use a state manager like vuex. Probably out scope here though.

Comment: how can i assign new height using $ref and where should i place it?

Comment: in your parent component inside ScollToEnd  you can access this.$ref.myDiv.scrollTop